# Third party WMS getcapability URL

Tags: geoserver, wms

i need some third party WMS Getcapabilities URLs. From where i can get those URLs. I want to test those URLs in my Geoserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Available+WMS+and+WFS+servers